# Can't stop Redux actions from being logged in console

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, action

All of a sudden my console is cluttered with redux actions that have been dispatched.

The place this originates from is `webpack:///./src/backend/index.ts`. There's an eventListener here on "message". Unfortunately I have no clue where to locate this file. Its not coming from a specific repo. Its happening in whatever project I open that dispatches Redux actions.

This is making by debug life a living hell. All help much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using redux-logger middleware in your project ?

Comment: I have used it in a project a while back but not in any of the projects where I see this occuring now.

Comment: Can you please recheck your `createStore` code and confirm if logger middleware is being used there ? Or maybe have a look at `console.log` statements used in your project. Because AFAIK redux doesn't support logging actions by default.

Comment: I just checked the function and all the middleware that is added is history, thunk and the redux devtools extension

Comment: I have the feeling something sneaked inside my global node modules but thats as far as Ive got

Answer (score 0):

Found the culprit. The chrome extension reactime was causing it.